# ExactSize attribute, data annotation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Inside my model I have property which needs to be exact size of type `integer`.

I know for attributes `Range` and `MaxLenght`, is there for exact size?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *exact size*?

Comment: exact size of 6 integers or strings for example.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Maybe you could provide some specific code sample?

Comment: for example: every citizen has unique exact number of 13 digits in my country, not 12, not 14 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `[RegularExpression]` attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{13,13}", ErrorMessage = "You must input exactly 13 digits")]
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```